# how to give two value for a string

Tags: python, string

```
import re
mysentence = 'have a dog a cute cat and a big cow '
myanimal = 'dog', 'cat' , 'cow'
print re.finditer('have(.*?)myanimal',mysentence)
```

this is not working , as my animal strings are not taken . Any idea to make it work ?

Comment: Can you share some more detail what do you expect as output here..

Answer (score 1):

Q> my animal strings are not taken

As you have myanimal inside the quotations ('have(.*?)myanimal') it would be considered as part of the string, it's actual values won't be substituted.

A regex needs to be formed, and since myanimal is list:

```
for animal in myanimal:
    regex = re.compile('have a .*%s'%animal)
    for m in re.finditer(regex, mysentence):
        print m.group()

output:
have a dog
have a dog a cute cat
have a dog a cute cat and a big cow
```

May be this could help....

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> mysentence = 'have a dog a cute cat and a big cow '
>>> myanimal = 'dog', 'cat' , 'cow'
>>> m = re.match(r'have a (?:%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, myanimal)), mysentence)
>>> m.group()
'have a dog'
```